# lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have an issue and rails s and rails c is not working anymore, i already tried many things, i hope you will help me. In my terminal i have this message:

`````
/Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:80:in `register'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:36:in `rescue in require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:25:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:48:in `configure_sass'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:13:in `load!'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:78:in `<main>'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/code/Caro1990/good_meal/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/code/Caro1990/good_meal/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
  from /Users/carolinemaze/code/Caro1990/good_meal/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
  from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
  from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'````
`````

I already tried:

- gem install bundler
- rails app:update:bin
- bundle update rails
- gem sources -r http://gems.rubyforge.org/
- gem sources -r http://gems.github.com
- gem sources -l ...

thank you for your help !!

Update: my gemfile:

```
ruby '2.4.5'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'money-rails'
gem "pundit"
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'gibbon'
gem 'figaro'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

gemfile.lock:

```
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
    activerecord (5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.6.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (9.4.9)
      execjs
    bcrypt (3.1.12)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.4.1)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sassc (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (11.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.4)
    crass (1.0.4)
    devise (4.6.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 6.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dotenv (2.7.1)
    dotenv-rails (2.7.1)
      dotenv (= 2.7.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 6.1)
    erubi (1.8.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    faraday (0.15.4)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.10.0)
    figaro (1.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    font-awesome-sass (5.0.13)
      sassc (>= 1.11)
    gibbon (3.2.0)
      faraday (>= 0.9.1)
      multi_json (>= 1.11.0)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.5.3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    json (2.2.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.7.0)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.3)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.2)
    mimemagic (0.3.3)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    monetize (1.9.1)
      money (~> 6.12)
    money (6.13.2)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 2)
    money-rails (1.13.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      monetize (~> 1.9.0)
      money (~> 6.13.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    msgpack (1.2.6)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.10.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    postmark (1.15.0)
      json
    postmark-rails (0.19.0)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.0)
      postmark (~> 1.15.0)
    pry (0.12.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    pry-byebug (3.7.0)
      byebug (~> 11.0)
      pry (~> 0.10)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    puma (3.12.0)
    pundit (2.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    rack (2.0.6)
    rack-proxy (0.6.5)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.1)
      actioncable (= 5.2.1)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      actionview (= 5.2.1)
      activejob (= 5.2.1)
      activemodel (= 5.2.1)
      activerecord (= 5.2.1)
      activestorage (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.1)
      actionpack (= 5.2.1)
      activesupport (= 5.2.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.19.0, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.1.0)
    responders (2.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 6.0)
    sassc (2.0.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
      rake
    sassc-rails (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    simple_form (4.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.9)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.8)
      rack (>= 2.0.6)
    web-console (3.7.0)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    webpacker (3.5.5)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  autoprefixer-rails
  bootsnap
  bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3)
  devise
  dotenv-rails
  figaro
  font-awesome-sass (~> 5.0.9)
  gibbon
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  letter_opener
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  money-rails
  pg (~> 0.21)
  postmark-rails
  pry-byebug
  pry-rails
  puma
  pundit
  rails (= 5.2.1)
  redis
  sassc-rails
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  uglifier
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webpacker

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.4.5p335

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.1
```

application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module GoodMeal
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |generate|
          generate.assets false
          generate.helper false
          generate.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
        end
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end



# POUR ACTIVER .ENV
Dotenv::Railtie.load

HOSTNAME = ENV['HOSTNAME']


end
```

bin/rails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

boot.rb:

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
require 'bootsnap/setup' # Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution of my problem: I update my ruby version and I had in the Gemefile: gem 'sass-rails', require: false. And now It's work. Thank you everyone for your help.

```
ruby '2.5.3'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', require: false
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'rails', '5.2.1'
gem 'redis'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'money-rails'
gem "pundit"
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'gibbon'
# gem 'figaro'

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'letter_opener'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails', :require => 'dotenv/rails-now'
  gem 'dotenv'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line in the logs:

`from /Users/carolinemaze/code/Caro1990/good_meal/config/application.rb:7:`

It seems your code is requiring a file that doesn't exist anymore. You can find exactly what's happening in `config/application.rb:7`

Also, try to remove `gem 'sassc-rails'` from `group :assets`

Comment: Thank you in this file rb:7 I have ```Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)```, i still don't know the issue...

Comment: Do you have `gem 'sassc-rails'` in your gemfile? Can you put it before `gem 'rails'` then do `bundle install` and try to run the app server again?

Comment: I tried to do it: put gem 'sassc-rails' before gem 'rails' and do bundle install but i still have the same issue...

Comment: Thanks! Can you update your question and add your gemfile to it?

Comment: Also if you have `gem 'sassc-rails'` in `group :assets` try to remove it out of there and try to `bundle install` and run the server again

Comment: I put my gemfile but i don't have group:assets

Comment: Thanks for that! Can you put `gem 'sassc-rails'` on the top of gemfile just for it to be before `gem 'rails', '5.2.1'` ? then try to `bundle install` and see if the server gives the same error or not?

Comment: still the same issue when i put gem 'sassc-rails' before 'rails', '5.2.1' then bundle install and 'rails s'

Comment: Sorry but can you update your question once again posting your `application.rb` and `bin/rails` ?

Comment: Also can you try to go to your project directory, then go to `tmp/cache` and if you found `bootsnap-load-path-cache` and `bootsnap-compile-cache` can you remove them?

Comment: nothing happen when i remove the files... still the same issue when i try rails s

Comment: Thanks Caroline! Can you not only delete the files but the whole directory which they were? Also can you try to do `bundle update bootsnap` ?

Comment: Also can you share your `boot.rb` file?

Comment: I tried bundle update bootsnap but it still not working... and I had my file boot.rb... thank you for your help !!

Comment: Can you remove this line `bootsnap/setup` in `boot.rb` and try again?

Comment: I already did it but I still have the same issue... thank you amrdruid for your help