# lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

After trying to update an old Rails app, including Ruby, i got an error when i tried to launch a server, launch a rails update app and much more commands.

**Configuration Initial (to update project) :**

- Ruby 2.6.6
- Rails 5.2

to

- Ruby 3.1.2
- Rails 6.1.6

**My error :**

```
/Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)
```

**--trace**

```
➜  getin git:(update_to_3.1.2) ✗ rails s       
Calling `DidYouMean::SPELL_CHECKERS.merge!(error_name => spell_checker)' has been deprecated. Please call `DidYouMean.correct_error(error_name, spell_checker)' instead.
/Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:48:in `configure_sass'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:13:in `load!'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:78:in `<main>'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/code/BasileM/getin/config/application.rb:6:in `<main>'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/code/BasileM/getin/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/basile/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /Users/basile/code/BasileM/getin/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I tried manies "solutions" unsuccessful :

- add gem 'sass-rails'
- add gem 'sassc-rails' before gem rails
- gem install bundler
- bundle update rails
- also looked on that issue who looks like mine : [lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54888332/lib-bootsnap-load-path-cache-core-ext-kernel-require-rb21in-require-cannot)
- ...

**My gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '3.1.2'

gem 'bootsnap'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
gem 'puma', '>= 4.3.12'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0'
gem 'redis'
gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.9'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'rename'
gem 'searchkick'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.12.0'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem "actionview", ">= 5.2.2.1"
gem 'cookies_eu'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', require: false
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.9', '>= 4.9.4'
gem 'activestorage-validator'
gem "chartkick"
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2.4'
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'ahoy_matey'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'clipboard-rails'
gem 'pagy', '~> 3.5'
gem "net-smtp", require: false

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'letter_opener', :group => :development
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
end
```

**Gemfile.lock:**

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.6.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.6.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
    activerecord (6.1.6.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
    activestorage (6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      marcel (~> 1.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activestorage-validator (0.2.2)
      rails (>= 6.0.4.1)
    activesupport (6.1.6.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    acts_as_votable (0.12.1)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    ahoy_matey (4.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      device_detector
      safely_block (>= 0.2.1)
    autoprefixer-rails (10.4.7.0)
      execjs (~> 2)
    aws-eventstream (1.2.0)
    aws-partitions (1.613.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.131.5)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.525.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1, >= 1.6.1)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.58.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.127.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.114.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.127.0)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.4)
    aws-sigv4 (1.5.1)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.18)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.13.0)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    chartkick (4.2.0)
    clipboard-rails (1.7.1)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.10)
    cookies_eu (1.7.8)
      js_cookie_rails (~> 2.2.0)
    crass (1.0.6)
    device_detector (1.0.7)
    devise (4.8.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise_invitable (2.0.6)
      actionmailer (>= 5.0)
      devise (>= 4.6)
    digest (3.1.0)
    dotenv (2.8.1)
    dotenv-rails (2.8.1)
      dotenv (= 2.8.1)
      railties (>= 3.2)
    errbase (0.2.2)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    font-awesome-sass (5.0.13)
      sassc (>= 1.11)
    friendly_id (5.2.5)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    groupdate (6.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
    hashie (5.0.0)
    i18n (1.12.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jmespath (1.6.1)
    jquery-rails (4.5.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    js_cookie_rails (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    json (2.6.2)
    launchy (2.5.0)
      addressable (~> 2.7)
    letter_opener (1.8.1)
      launchy (>= 2.2, < 3)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.18.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.8.0)
    minitest (5.16.2)
    msgpack (1.5.4)
    net-protocol (0.1.3)
      timeout
    net-smtp (0.3.1)
      digest
      net-protocol
      timeout
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.8)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.8.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pagy (3.11.0)
    pg (0.21.0)
    postmark (1.22.1)
      json
    postmark-rails (0.22.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.0.0)
      postmark (>= 1.21.3, < 2.0)
    pry (0.13.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    pry-byebug (3.9.0)
      byebug (~> 11.0)
      pry (~> 0.13.0)
    pry-rails (0.3.9)
      pry (>= 0.10.4)
    public_suffix (4.0.7)
    puma (5.6.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    pundit (2.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.4)
    rack-proxy (0.7.2)
      rack
    rack-test (2.0.2)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    rails (6.1.6.1)
      actioncable (= 6.1.6.1)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.6.1)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      actiontext (= 6.1.6.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.6.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.6.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.6.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.6.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.6.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.3)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.6.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.6.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.6.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 12.2)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.1)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    redis (4.7.1)
    rename (1.0.8)
      activesupport
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
      thor (>= 0.19.1)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    safely_block (0.3.0)
      errbase (>= 0.1.1)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    searchkick (5.0.4)
      activemodel (>= 5.2)
      hashie
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    simple_form (5.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activemodel (>= 5.2)
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.2.1)
    tilt (2.0.11)
    timeout (0.3.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    uglifier (4.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webpacker (5.4.3)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    zeitwerk (2.6.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  actionview (>= 5.2.2.1)
  activestorage-validator
  acts_as_votable (~> 0.12.0)
  ahoy_matey
  autoprefixer-rails
  aws-sdk-s3
  bootsnap
  chartkick
  clipboard-rails
  cookies_eu
  devise
  devise_invitable (~> 2.0.0)
  dotenv-rails
  font-awesome-sass (~> 5.0.9)
  friendly_id (~> 5.2.4)
  groupdate
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  letter_opener
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  mini_magick (~> 4.9, >= 4.9.4)
  net-smtp
  pagy (~> 3.5)
  pg (~> 0.21)
  postmark-rails
  pry-byebug
  pry-rails
  puma (>= 4.3.12)
  pundit
  rails (~> 6.0)
  redis
  rename
  sass-rails
  searchkick
  simple_form
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  uglifier
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webpacker

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 3.1.2p20

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

**application.rb:**

```
require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Getin
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |generate|
          generate.assets false
          generate.helper false
          generate.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
        end
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

**boot.rb:**

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
require 'bootsnap/setup' # Speed up boot time by caching expensive operations.
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I suggest you update one at a time and in small steps. What happens if you update only ruby from 2.6 to 2.7? Is everything ok? Try updating rails from 5.2 to 6.0...

Comment: Hi @PedroPaiva,
I tried but still have the same issue.

Comment: But the problem appeared in which minor update?

Answer (score 0):

In ruby 2.5.3, Rails 5.2.8.1, webpack@5.46.0

I got the same issue with you.
And I resolve the problem by removing my project's

> tmp/cache

if this can't resolve then adding this in Gemfile

```
gem 'rexml', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.5'
```

try bundle install.